Dependencia en android studio

Buenas, soy nuevo en el área de Android studio y necesito importar unas libreas en la parte de dependencia , pero el método que he aprendido me da error, y siempre sucede con todas las librerías externas que quiero exportar. ¿Cómo hago o que método utilizo para que no suceda este error?

Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. ¿cuál es el método que utilizas? ¿cuál es el mensaje de error?
